# convolution of two signals with different step responses

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, convolution

[image]

for the given signal h(n), is it 1 for n=0:149 or the n's of each is a different thing?

Comment: I'm afraid this is a homework question with zero effort on the OP's side.

Answer (score 1):

The n's represent samples because you are working with discrete signals. They are not all 1. For n=0:149 every sample is incremented by 1.If you write n=0:149 in MATLAB you will get a vector 1x150 with elements 0,1,2,3.....149.
I recommend the book *Digital Signal Processing Using MATLAB* by *Vinay K. Ingle and John G. Proakis*

```
n = 0:149; %n = [0,1,2,3...149]
h = 3*(0.5).^n.*(stepfun(n,0)-stepfun(n,100))-2*(1/3).^n.*(stepfun(n,0)-stepfun(n,50));
x = stepfun(n,0)-stepfun(n,70);
y = conv(h,x);
stem(y);
```